# Performance issue with WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, clr

I am facing a strange issue that throws following exception.

> **The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x22f3090 to COM context 0x22f32e0 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.**

So, I am keen to know its possible reasons in wpf. As of now, I am performing an operation which is causing this So, I put stop watch and check the time of my code but my code is not taking time to execute rather it is taken by run time framework. I know probably I am doing something wrong with my code. So, I am keen to know the possible reason for this kind of bug.. currently Invoking that operation is taking more than 5 minutes and even operation is very simple

Comment: or any way to track down the root cause in the code for introducing this problem

Comment: You should post the code, which causes this exception.

Comment: Actual, I don't know which piece of code is doing it and I also want to know the same.

Comment: well, you are saying, that it happens when you are "performing a very simple operation". So there is clearly something wrong with it or with the way you perform it. I seriously doubt that it is a WPF issue, more likely it is something you wrote.

Comment: Ok, the operation is that I am just showing 3 Grids on the operation ,For that I am checking the time taken to populate the grid's data source that is very nominal.

Comment: Post your code. It is impossible to debug anything without seeing it :)

Comment: Is this happening at normal runtime, or while you are debugging? I've only ever seen this exception in the debugger when I was stepping through stuff

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer yes I am also getting in debug mode. but I want to know why a normal operation is taking so much time. is it beacause of this exception or something elese

Comment: The exception is a symptom of a problem in your code. You will have to post your code for us to help further.

Comment: probable solution: delete all your (horrible winforms-like) code behind and create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and do any background operations in the ViewModel level without touching the UI and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: BTW, I seen this issue a couple of times when `F5`ing a huge WPF project. Simply stop debugging and try again and it doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: @HighCore, why are you assuming there's "horrible winforms-like code behind" out there?

Comment: @Noseration I've seen this error on badly implemented code that messes up with the UI rather than using proper Databinding. When trying to execute that code in a background thread or the like, it blows up, and `some`times you get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lots of efforts, I came to know that I was making a silly mistake by putting a data grid inside a scroll bar, which disables the by default visualization(UI and Data), and It was trying to load all the objects in the grid regardless of their need,

So, good note:

Never ever place scroll bar outside a **grid.

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <DataGrid>
....
  </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>**
```

Never do this.